# TFS resolve conflicts but no changes appear to be happening

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012, azure-devops-server-2019

I have an SSRS package in TFS, when I try to get the latest version, I get a conflict.
When I try to compare local to server, there are no changes (no red zones) between the local version and the server version for that SSRS package.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: How did you resolve the conflict? You may need to check if the changes in your local code are same as that on your sever. And when you resolved the conflict, you merged these changes to make no differences between them.

You can try to extract the latest version on your server and the latest version on your local. Then use a comparison tool to compare the two versions to see if they have any differences.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT that's what I did weh I compare the two versions, they are identical I don't know why

Comment: Hi @MartinJames, before you made changes on local code, had you synced or download the latest code version from your server to the local. After you have made changes in local code and before checking in the changes from local to server, you also need to compare the original code version that you synced or downloaded to local from server with the current latest code version on server. This is to check if any changes have been checked in to server during you make changes on your local. If there are some changes checked in to server during you make local changes, you need to merge these changes.